# How can I connect my Unity android app to a 000webhost database?

Tags: c#, android, sql, unity-game-engine

I'm making a Unity Android app that displays info from a database.

For that I used 000WebHost to make a website and a sql server. When I test the app with Unity in my computer, it works fine, a bit of loading time required, but it works perfectly.

But, when I build the apk and test it on my phone, it doesn't work. It gets stuck in the "loading text" screen I made and never loads the text from the database.

I have a log error in Unity that activates when the connection fails, and I suppose the same is happening here.

Is there a way to solve it or is it because i'm a free user?

Here are the codes:

WebTextLoader.cs (Unity/Displays text from the database)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class WebTextLoader : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Serializable]
    public class PlaceInfo
    {
        public string Titulo = "";
        public string Texto = "";
    }

    public string URL;  //example: https://arguidetest.000webhostapp.com/pruebaMedieval.php
    public Text TituloUI; 
    public Text TextoUI;

    public PlaceInfo placeInfo;
    public void Start()
    {
        if (Debug.isDebugBuild)
        {
            StartCoroutine(GetRequest(URL));

        }
    }
    IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
        {
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            string jsonForm = uri;

            if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log("Error loading");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    placeInfo = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlaceInfo>(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                    TituloUI.text = placeInfo.Titulo;
                    TextoUI.text = placeInfo.Texto;

                }
                catch
                {
                    Debug.Log("Error in connection");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

pruebaMedieval.php (000webhost / turns an array of title and text into a JSon)

```php
<?php 

    $server = ***;
    $usuario = ***;
    $pass = ***;
    $database= ***;

    $mysqli = new mysqli($server, $usuario, $pass, $database);

    $query = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM INFORMACION_EVENTOS where id = 1");

        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

            $titulo = $valores["titulo"];
            $info = $valores["informacion"];

            $array = array(
                "Titulo" => $titulo,
                "Texto" => $info
            );
        }

    $result = json_encode($array);
    echo $result;
?>
```

Also, in Unity player settings I have the internet connection as Require.

Sorry for the wall of text

Comment: Just a FYI don't include user names or database names, I could now brute force my way into your database far easier. But I digress, your connecting to the web server not the database server in Unity, big difference. You might need to enable CORS and/or drop HTTPS for Unity

Comment: When I try to open your site, Edge says hell no. So you should move the domain

Comment: @PhilipRollins Weird, I can enter my site from my computer/cellphone and so can my teacher from his cellphone (idk about his computer).

I'd change it but I can't since I have no money...yet